# ¿Por qué en mi escena es diferente en mi juego?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Estoy intentando aprender Unity haciendo un mapa base con un jugador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayer, cuando pulsaba el botón de play podía testear el juego perfectamente, pero hoy no funciona, creo que no he tocado nada...

Esto es lo que veo desde la tab de Game:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo mostrar en la tab de Game lo que veo en la tab de Scene? Me refiero a ver el mapa y el jugador. Únicamente puedo ver el Canvas ahora mismo...

Edit: traducido al Español, ni me di cuenta del dominio .es

Comment: Hola esta es la comunidad de SO en español, te recomiendo que hagas esta pregunta en https://stackoverflow.com/ o la realices en español. Saludos!

Comment: Si tu mismo has encontrado la solución y has agregado la respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias.  Mira [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428) para aprender a aceptar respuesta y este [otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para conocer porque es importante aceptarlas. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que se me ha reseteado Z en MainCamera, no tengo ni idea de como ha pasado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ponerlo en -10 ha vuelto a funcionar